# Sorting non IComparable objects

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, sorting, constraints

According documentation:

> `System.Array.Sort<T>` - sorts the elements in an entire System.Array using the System.IComparable generic interface implementation of each element of the System.Array.

Today I discover, that this code is compiling without any errors and warnings:

```
A []arr = new A[10];//A is not inheriting from IComparable !!

//initializing elements of arr
...

System.Array.Sort<A>(arr);
```

After execution I'm getting run-time error.

So why this code is compiling? I'm not big expert of C#, but I know, that C# generics supporting constraining syntax. Why constraints aren't used for Array.Sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *compiles* because there's no constraint on `T` that it has to implement `IComparable<T>`.

I think the documentation is slightly confusing, because the array elements don't *actually* have to implement `IComparable<T>` for the same `T` as the call. For example, this works fine:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        object[] objects = { "d", "b", "c", "a" };        
        Array.Sort<object>(objects);
    }
}
```

I think it's more sensible to just say that the elements have to be comparable with each other "somehow". For example, this is fine, even though nothing's implementing the *generic* `IComparable` interface:

```
using System;

class A : IComparable
{
    private readonly int value;

    public A(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object other)
    {
        // Just cast for now...
        return value.CompareTo(((A)other).value);
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        object[] objects = { new A(5), new A(3), new A(4) };
        Array.Sort<object>(objects);
    }
}
```

Comment: So purpose of not using constraint on types is to  be able to sort objects, that implement  `IComparable` but don't implement `IComparable<T>`?

Comment: @Ashot: As far as I can tell, yes.